# Decision can match input such

Tags: antlrworks

> Hello, i am having many erros "decision can match input such" with my
>   combined grammar, i try to solve theses but i don't succeed. Can
>   someone help me? thanks!

```
  options{ k=1; language= Java; output= AST;

}

prog    : exp   
    ;
exp     : lval          
    | 'NIL'             
    | INT               
    | 'STRING'  
    | '(' exp_seq ')'       
    | ID ST 
    | lval ':=' exp             
    |'IF' exp 'THEN' exp EL
    | 'WHILE' exp 'DO' exp      
    | 'FOR' ID ':=' exp 'TO' exp 'DO' exp   
    | 'BREAK'               
    | 'LET' decs 'IN' exp_seq 'END' 
    |compor
    ;

ST  :  '(' args ')' 
    | '{' rcd '}'       
    |  '[' exp ']' 'OF' exp 
    ;

EL      :   'ELSE' exp  
        |
        ;    
    /* 
exp_t   : expp exp_t
    |
    ;   







OP  : '*'       
    |  '/'          
    |  '-'              

    | '+'
    |  '>'          
    |  '<'          
    |  '>='             
    |  '<='         
    |  '&'              
    |  '|'          
    |  '='          
    |  '<>'     
        ;     

        */
exp_seq :       
    | exp exp_seq_t         
    ;

exp_seq_t :     
     | ';' exp exp_seq_t    
     ;

decs :      
    | tydec decs            
    | vardec decs           
    | fundec decs           
    ;

tydec : 'TYPE' ID '=' ty    
    ;

ty : ID         
    | '{' tyfs '}'  
    | 'ARRAY' 'OF' ID       
    ;

tyfs :      
    | ID ':' ID tyfs_t  
    ;

tyfs_t : 
    | ',' ID ':' ID tyfs_t  
         ;

vardec : 'var' ID var_t     

    ;

var_t   : ':=' exp  
    | ':' ID ':=' exp   
    ;
    fundec : 'FUNCTION' ID '(' tyfs ')' Func_t 
           ;



Func_t  : '=' exp   
    | ',' ID '='exp 
    ;   

args    : exp args_t        
        | 
        ;

args_t :        
    | ','exp args_t     
    ;

rcd :   ID '='exp rcd_t     
       | 
    ;

rcd_t :             
    | ',' 'ID' '='exp rcd_t     
    ;

lval : ID       
    | T lval_t  
    ;
T   : '.' ID
        | '[' exp ']'
        ;   


lval_t : T lval_t   
    |   
    ;

    INT : '0'..'9'+ ;
    ID : ( 'a'..'z'| 'A' .. 'Z')+ ;
/*  STRING : ( 'a'..'z'| 'A' .. 'Z')+ ; */


/*  DIV :'/' ;
    MUL:'*' ;
    MINUS : '-' ;
    PLUS : '+' ;
    OR : ('|');
    AND: ('&');
    LE : '<=' ;
    GE : '>=' ;
    GT :'>' ;
    LT :'<' ;
    EQ: '=';
    OPINCONNU :'<>';  */

atom    : '('exp')'
        | INT   
        | ID var_t
        ;

compor: compend or_bis?
     ;
or_bis  :'|' compend
    ;        

compend : comp compend_bis? 
    ;
compend_bis: '&' comp 
    ;           

 comp   : add comp_bis? 
     ;

comp_bis :'<=' add
     |'>=' add
     |'>' add
     |'<' add
     |'=' add
     |'<>' add
     ;

 add    : mult add_bis*   
        ;

 add_bis :'+'mult
         |'-'mult
         ;       

 mult   : neg mult_bis* 
    ;

mult_bis : '*' neg
     | '/' neg
     ;  

neg : ('-')? atom 
    ;       


    /*
MUL  DIV 

PLUS  MINUS
OR LE GE LT GT OPINCONNU EQ AND */
NOT_WS: ~('\...\ ' |' '| '\t' | '\n' | '\r'); ##
```

#### - errors:

- erros: [ Decision can match input such as "T" using multiple
  alternatives: 1, 7 As a result, alternative(s) 7 were disabled for
  that input  Decision can match input such as "'('" using multiple
  alternatives: 5, 13 As a result, alternative(s) 13 were disabled for
  that input  Decision can match input such as "ID" using multiple
  alternatives: 1, 6, 7, 13 As a result, alternative(s) 6,7,13 were
  disabled for that input [01:03:59] warning(200): tiger.g:15:9:
  Decision can match input such as "INT" using multiple alternatives:
  3, 13 As a result, alternative(s) 13 were disabled for that input
  [01:03:59] error(201): tiger.g:15:9: The following alternatives can
  never be matched: 6,7

  Decision can match input such as "'|'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'&'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'<='" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'<>'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'<'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
  Decision can match input such as "'='" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'>='" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'>'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'+'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input 
  Decision can match input such as "'-'" using multiple alternatives:
  1, 2 As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
  [01:03:59] warning(200): tiger.g:225:13: Decision can match i

nput such as "'*'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
 Decision can match input such as "'/'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
[ Decision can match input such as "T" using multiple alternatives: 1, 7
As a result, alternative(s) 7 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'('" using multiple alternatives: 5, 13
As a result, alternative(s) 13 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "ID" using multiple alternatives: 1, 6, 7, 13
As a result, alternative(s) 6,7,13 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "INT" using multiple alternatives: 3, 13
As a result, alternative(s) 13 were disabled for that input The following alternatives can never be matched: 6,7

Decision can match input such as "'|'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'&'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'<='" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'<>'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
 Decision can match input such as "'<'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'='" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'>='" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'>'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
 Decision can match input such as "'+'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'-'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'*'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
Decision can match input such as "'/'" using multiple alternatives: 1, 2
As a result, alternative(s) 2 were disabled for that input
 reference to undefined rule: exp
 reference to undefined rule: exp
 reference to undefined rule: exp
 reference to undefined rule: exp
 reference to undefined rule: exp
reference to undefined rule: rcd
 reference to undefined rule: exp